# centos 8 on build docker error :Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, ssl, centos

I try to run it from Visual Studio Code can find the local database and connect to it. change database setting the environment variable run docker container， But when I run the app in the docker container cannot connect to the database the running container it returns this error :

[image]

I try openssl build tecmint.local.crt and tecmint.local.key
Copy the **tecmint.local.crt** file to two directory:

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
```

and

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
```

#centos 8 directory#

```
[root@localhost extra]# cd /etc/ssl/private
[root@localhost private]# ls
tecmint.local.crt  tecmint.local.key
[root@localhost extra]# cd /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
[root@localhost anchors]# ls
openssl-1.1.1k  openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz  tecmint.local.crt
[root@localhost anchors]# cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
[root@localhost extra]# ls
tecmint.local.crt
```

then docker run dockerfile

and Mount the certs onto the Docker container using :

```
docker run -v /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra:/app/build -d 39bc3b53bb17 "update-ca-certificates"
```

#Dockerfile #

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8000

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MVCVue.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "MVCVue.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "MVCVue.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MVCVue.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MVCVue.dll"]
```

#Startup#

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<cpteContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));

           services.AddAntiforgery(opiton => {
           opiton.FormFieldName = "MyAntiForgeryField";
           opiton.HeaderName = "ANTI-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";
});
        }
```

#DbContext#

```
    public partial class testContext : DbContext
    {
        public cpteContext(){}
        public cpteContext(DbContextOptions<cpteContext> options)  : base(options){}
        public virtual DbSet<Board> Boards { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Operator> Operators { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                           .Build();
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase"); 
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }

        }
```

#appsettings.json#

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=testdb;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=myid;Password=myPassword;Integrated Security=false;"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On many Linux distributions, the OpenSSL configuration file is at /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.

code add-in openssl.cnf

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[ default_conf ]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.0
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux

openssl.cnf copy in /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf

or

use the following workaround in Dockerfile.

```
RUN sed -i 's/TLSv1.2/TLSv1.0/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Reference :https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/11249

if is Server Certificate validation when TLS encryption is enforced by the target Server you must at least add this setting to your connection string (to enforce use of SSL):

```
trustservercertificate=true
```

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/633